# MySQL: select column1 where column2 contains X but not Y and Z and column1 equal to 1234

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT member if level is 2 but not 4 or 5 where member equal to 1234

```
id  | member | level    
1   | 1234   | 2    
2   | 1234   | 4    
3   | 1234   | 5
```

So based on above table select should not return member because they also have level 4 and 5.

How to write it in MySQL query please?

Comment: There are no member 12345. Typo?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it meant to be 1234.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT member 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY member
HAVING SUM(level = 2) > 0 AND SUM(level IN (4, 5)) = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4de847/2)